# Why more memory (than being required) is allocated to a struct with flexible array member in cfg80211 scan request?

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, flexible-array-member

I am learning linux wifi drivers, and was exploring the code in `cfg80211` subsytem for a scan request.

I can't understand why the following `struct` is allocated more memory than required. 
Or, I can't understand the way the size of memory to be allocated is calculated in this way.

The `struct` is defined in [`include/net/cfg80211.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f0b5989745c3e0e92424d36869a97e4e8df7ab13/include/net/cfg80211.h#L1973):

```c
struct cfg80211_scan_request {
    struct cfg80211_ssid *ssids;
    int n_ssids;
    u32 n_channels;
    enum nl80211_bss_scan_width scan_width;
    const u8 *ie;
    size_t ie_len;
    u16 duration;
    bool duration_mandatory;
    u32 flags;

    u32 rates[NUM_NL80211_BANDS];

    struct wireless_dev *wdev;

    u8 mac_addr[ETH_ALEN] __aligned(2);
    u8 mac_addr_mask[ETH_ALEN] __aligned(2);
    u8 bssid[ETH_ALEN] __aligned(2);

    /* internal */
    struct wiphy *wiphy;
    unsigned long scan_start;
    struct cfg80211_scan_info info;
    bool notified;
    bool no_cck;

    /* keep last */
    struct ieee80211_channel *channels[0];
};
```

In file [`/net/wireless/nl80211.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f0b5989745c3e0e92424d36869a97e4e8df7ab13/net/wireless/nl80211.c#L7734), memory is being allocated to the `struct` as follows:

```c
static int nl80211_trigger_scan(struct sk_buff *skb, struct genl_info *info)
{
    // ...
    struct cfg80211_scan_request *request;
    // ...
    request = kzalloc(sizeof(*request)
            + sizeof(*request->ssids) * n_ssids
            + sizeof(*request->channels) * n_channels
            + ie_len, GFP_KERNEL);
    // ...
}
```

I have a doubt that more memory is being allocated than required. Or, the way size is calculated in `kzalloc` doesn't make sense to me.

This is what I expect the code to be like:

```c
static int nl80211_trigger_scan(struct sk_buff *skb, struct genl_info *info)
{
    // ...
    struct cfg80211_scan_request *request;
    // ...
    request = kzalloc(sizeof(*request)
            + sizeof(*request->channels) * n_channels, 
              GFP_KERNEL);
    // ...
}
```

Why that much size of memory is allocated then? 
What I'm understanding is `kzalloc(struct + flexible_array_member + extra_len_but_why)`.

Comment: I'm guessing that's because there is extra data after that that's not actually a `struct ieee80211_channel`.

Comment: In terms of Standard C, that's not a flexible array member; it's just a mistake because zero-sized arrays are illegal and a FAM has an empty dimension: `struct ieee80211_channel *channels[];`.  It's using a GCC extension — it's debatable whether it is one or two extensions, but it hardly matters.  OTOH, it works, and the Linux kernel is definitely dependent on GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the code after the `kzalloc` sets the values of the pointers `requests->ssids` and `requests->ie` so that they point into the newly allocated memory, just after the struct.

That way, only one block of memory needs to be allocated for the three arrays.

**EDIT**: I found the function in question, and indeed, just after the kzalloc call shown in the OP, we find the following, which sets up the `ssids` and `ie` pointers:

```
if (n_ssids)
    request->ssids = (void *)&request->channels[n_channels];
request->n_ssids = n_ssids;
if (ie_len) {
    if (n_ssids)
        request->ie = (void *)(request->ssids + n_ssids);
    else
        request->ie = (void *)(request->channels + n_channels);
}
```